# Verify Object Fields can be Updated without Using a Loop (Java)

Tags: java

I would like to be able to verify that I can update all the requested fields in a class can be updated without looping through them one-by-one in a loop or similar mechanism. Here is the use case:

I have a class with dozens of fields. Of those dozens of fields, only a subset are allowed to be updated (in the corresponding persisted data object the class maps to in a datastore). Further, the updateable ones can change over time. To allow for this, the updatable fields are captured in an application.properties file as a single property captured as comma-separated fields (String, int, whatever) of a class.

So for example, lets say I have a class:

```
public class Car {
    String wheel;
    String engine;
    String transmission;
    String color;
}
```

, and a property in application.properties:

```
    car.editable=car.wheel,car.color
```

At runtime, I will read the car class properties, presumably into a corresponding Car object that simply indicates that (in this point in time) only the car wheel and color are editable. At that same time, I have a user calling my endpoint (lets assume I have a updateCar endpoint), and his car request object wants to update everything (wheel, engine, transmission, color).

I would like to avoid looping through each field in the class. Is there some mechanism in java where I could simply map the one car object against the other and return an allowed/not-allowed response? Ideally with a detail of why it is not allowed if that is the case.

Thanks for any clever ideas.

Comment: Are you considering any framework like spring boot in which you can create field level validation using custom annotations ?

Comment: @DattaDiware that sounds like a good solution. I am in a springboot environment. We could have an \@Immutable annotation that would keep us from updating fields that are essentially immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you already know which Car properties are editable, you can store them as enum values in an `EnumSet`.

Then, when an update request arrives, you create another `EnumSet` and fill it with fields a user wants to update. To check if the operation is allowed, simply call `EnumSet#containsAll` to see if the requested fields are in the allowed set.

A much better way would be to use a mapping framework, such as Orika Mapper, or MapStruct. You could then implement methods that would try to map the DTO with update request to your Car class and throw an exception if such mapping is disallowed.

Comment: thanks for your great suggestion. I have reviewed MapStruct and love its powerful way of addressing certain mapping challenges. However what I have is a one class where all fields are updatable and I second where class with identical structure has same fields but not all are updateable. I am not sure how I would address that with MapStruct.

Comment: @Leprechaun what's makes you think that EnumSets contains all does not iterate over the items ?

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy I see no problem here. In Mapstruct you define/write mapping rules for mapping from class A to class B. If you have class C that has the same fields as class B, but different mutability rules, you write a different mapping from A to C.

Comment: @DattaDiware Obviously, some form of iteration is unavoidable if you want to check for each element or field. The way OP phrased the question I figured he just wants to avoid manually checking each field. see: "Is there some mechanism in java where I could simply map the one car object against the other and return an allowed/not-allowed response? "